# Rapid deceleration of the spaceship with the help of black hole

Tags: gravity, black-holes, tidal-effect, space-travel

Could a spaceship traveling close to the speed of light (ok, maybe speed is not relevant for this question) decelerate (almost stop) very quickly (say, on a safe distance) with the help of a very close black hole flyby?

What I mean to ask is if this could be a "method" for spaceships to stop very quickly when travelling with relativistic speeds. And if this would work, would there be any issues for astronauts to survive this (deceleration via gravity shouldn't have any effects right?)?

From my **layman** point of view the only issues would be tidal forces? That is - not survivable?

Comment: The problem with this idea is that if you only have one gravitating object like a black hole, it can slingshot you in a different direction at the same speed, but it can't stop you. You need ***two*** black holes orbiting each other to decelerate.

Comment: @PeterShor I'm not sure that this is true; it's pretty clear that gravity assists can both accelerate and decelerate objects: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist

Comment: -1. Unclear. What do you mean by "stop very quickly"? How quickly? If you mean "quickly enough to be survivable" then the question is tautological.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes I agree, I have retracted by close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need two black holes orbiting each other to decelerate the spacecraft. Gravity assists are possible, and have been used for spacecraft in the solar system. However, if you slingshot around an object, you cannot change your speed relative to that object.  So if there's only one black hole that you try to use to decelerate, you will end up traveling at the same speed relative to that black hole. Thus, you cannot use a single black hole for deceleration.

[See wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist).

> A slingshot maneuver can therefore be used to change the spaceship's trajectory and speed *relative to the Sun.*
>   ...
>   Interplanetary slingshots using the Sun itself are *not possible* because the Sun is at rest relative to the Solar System as a whole.  [italics added]

If the black hole was rotating rapidly, you might be able to decelerate using the black hole's rotation somehow. This would be solely a general relativity effect, and is not possible with classical physics. I don't know whether this would work. I suspect it wouldn't, but maybe somebody else could write an answer addressing this.

EDIT: A rotating black hole will not work.

Also, to do deceleration by the slingshot maneuver, you have to get close enough to the black hole to slingshot around it and make something like a 90 degree turn (otherwise you'll be taken away from the black hole system).  If I get a chance, I'll try to figure out what the tidal forces are for this, but I'm fairly sure that for black holes of a few solar masses, they aren't survivable. For supermassive black holes, the tidal forces would be survivable, but most supermassive black holes live in the center of galaxies and generate massive amounts of radiation, so these wouldn't be survivable for other reasons.

Comment: As far as I know, there aren't any GR effects that will help you out unless you're willing to split your spacecraft into two parts and throw one part away (as in the Penrose process).  But doing so is better known as "firing a rocket", in which case you could do it without the black hole in the first place.

Comment: Wouldn't the slingshot maneuver generate gravitational waves resulting in a loss of energy? If you approached the BH in such a way that you revolved around it a bunch of times before escaping, then wouldn't your relative escaping speed be less than your approach speed?

Comment: @AndrewSzymczak: good point. I don't know the size of this effect, though, and how much of the energy of gravitational waves comes from the black hole, and how much from the deceleration of your spaceship.